# UIAlertView scrolling issue

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

So I am using UIAlertView to show some content to the user. The content is really long followed by 4 buttons. Because of the length of the content, the whole thing cannot fit in a screen.

But instead of the content being scrollable, the button section (underneath the content) becomes scrollable which causes one of the buttons to be hidden to begin with (not very intuitive). I would like the content to scrollable instead.

Comment: I think you would have to write your own alert for that. Or you can try using the many cocoapods that provide a custom alert view.

Comment: I really don't wanna use a Cocoapod for just one alert. So do you mean, this is how the default behaviour is in iOS ?

Comment: Yes, `UIAlertController` isn't very customisable. You can write your own if you want.

Comment: If you don't want cocoa pods then write your own custom alert code.

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8. To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later, instead use [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) with a `preferredStyle` of `alert`. It will give you scrollable text with scrollable `action` also if they are not fit to screen.

```
let  alert = UIAlertController(title: YOUR_TITLE, message: YOUR_LONG_MESSAGE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.view.tintColor = .red
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay4", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer my question